# Can't install Package with pip

Tags: python, pip

I can't install `catboost` packages with pip. Error is following:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=my_port): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=my_port): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=my_port): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=my_port): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='my_host', port=my_port): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement catboost (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for catboost
```

How Can I handle it?

Comment: You are trying to connect to a host called `my_host` are you sure it exists?

Comment: Also, we need more information. Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: @MatteoZanoni I Change real host, port and address with My_host, my_port, and http://my_adress/api/pypi/python/simple/catboost; Indeed, I use real host, port and address

Comment: @Itération122442 I use proxy proxy to connect repository

Comment: Are you using a TCP proxy or a custom Pypi repository that mirrors Pypi? I do not understand your situation... What do you expect to be answering at `my_host`?